# ¿Cómo puedo añadir un espacio antes de una letra en mayúscula?

Tags: javascript, regex

Dada esta cadena:

```
AllThe-small Things
```

Quiero una expresión regular que lo convierta en:

```
All The-small Things
```

Esto es, un expresión del tipo:

```
otraStr = string.replace(/letrasmayúsculasjuntas/, separalas con un espacio)
```

Que conserve un único espacio entre *small* y *Things*.

Comment: Sería bueno que añadieras qué buscas, así como una expresión general. ¿Se trata de añadir un espacio antes de una mayúscula, si antes va una minúscula? Parece eso pero no queda claro.

Comment: @fedorqui Exacto, si. Perdón si no había quedado claro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que quieres es añadir un espacio antes de una letra mayúscula, si esta aparece pegada a una letra minúscula.

Es decir:

```
aA             -> a A
holaMundo      -> hola Mundo
holaMundoCruel -> hola Mundo Cruel
```

Para ello, capturemos la letra minúscula previa y la mayúscula que la sigue. Después, imprimámoslas con un espacio entre ambas:

```
otraStr = string.replace(/([a-z])([A-Z])/g, '$1 $2');
```

Veámoslo en acción:

```js
var string = 'AllThe-small Things';
var otraStr = string.replace(/([a-z])([A-Z])/g, '$1 $2');

alert(otraStr);

// Otro ejemplo
var string = 'holaMundoCruel';
var otraStr = string.replace(/([a-z])([A-Z])/g, '$1 $2');
alert(otraStr);
```

Si resulta que tu cadena tiene dos mayúsculas seguidas, pues no funcionaría. Si ese caso también quieres separarlo, usa una comprobación posterior que separe las mayúsculas juntas:

```
string = string.replace(/([A-Z])([A-Z])/g, '$1 $2')
```

```js
var string = 'AbraCaDaBrAA';
var otraStr = string.replace(/([a-z])([A-Z])/g, '$1 $2');
otraStr = otraStr.replace(/([A-Z])([A-Z])/g, '$1 $2');

alert(otraStr);
```

Ideas sacadas de [Insert space before capital letters](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5582228/1983854).

Answer (score 4):

```js
var string = 'AllThe-small Things';
var formateado = string.replace(/([A-Z])/g, ' $1').trim();
formateado = formateado.replace(/  +/g, ' ');

alert(formateado);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Creo que algo como esto podría valerte. Le he añadido un `trim()` para limpiar espacios al principio y al final de la frase (porque la expresión regular va a meter un espacio delante de las mayúsculas del principio de la frase).

Lo que hace el segundo parámetro que le paso a la primera invocación de la función `replace()` es:

- El `$1` es un patrón de reemplazo que hace referencia al carácter o conjunto de caracteres reemplazados, por lo que al pasar como parámetro el `string` `' $1'` se le está diciendo que delante del carácter reemplazado añada un espacio y que luego vuelva a insertar el carácter reemplazado.

**Edit**

Para eliminar los espacios duplicados, triplicados o más añadí un segundo `replace()`. Que sustituye la repetición consecutiva de espacios por uno solo.

Comment: Podrías añadir a la expresión regular que no haya un espacio antes: `/[^ ]([A-Z])/g` y te ahorras el segundo `replace`

Comment: @PabloLozano ¿Y si hay 3? No soy un experto en expresiones regulares por eso me fui a la opción más sencilla que se me ocurrió. ¿Se podría hacer eso con solo una expresión?